# getting BAD_EXCESS during kiwi testing,

Tags: ios, objective-c, testing, bdd, kiwi

I am working on kiwi framework for testing by following

```
myStack.m
- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void) push:(int)numberToPush {
    [self.data addObject:numberToPush];
}
- (int)top {
    return [[self.data lastObject] integerValue];

}
-(int)numberOfItem {
    return [self.data count];
}
```

and testing is

```
SPEC_BEGIN(MyStack)

describe(@"The stack", ^{
    __block MyStack    *stack;
    context(@"when created", ^{
        beforeAll(^{
            stack = [[MyStack alloc] init];
        });
        it(@"is not nil.", ^{
            [stack shouldNotBeNil];
        });


        it(@"allows me to count the item of stack", ^{
            [stack push:5];
            [[stack should] haveCountOf:1];
        });
    });
});
SPEC_END
```

However, I am getting BAD_EXCESS with `Expectations` testing.I dont know why getting this error. All helps are welcomed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to add an `int` to your `NSMutableArray`. You can only add objects to an `NSArray`, not primitive types. Try boxing in an `NSNumber` in your implementation of `push:`:

```c
- (void) push:(int)numberToPush {
    [self.data addObject:@(numberToPush)];
}
```